# What is the std::rotate() equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, std

I'm moving to C# from C++ and I have troubles with translating my project to C#. How to perform

```
std::rotate(alphabet.rbegin(), alphabet.rbegin() + 1, alphabet.rend());
```

with the help of C# tools where `alphabet` is a `std::string` with basic alphabet.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-rotation-right-rotation-string-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard library function that would do this for you, you need to implement it yourself. Here's probably the simplest way of doing that:

```cs
var result = alphabet.Substring(1) + alphabet[0];
```

This performs two string allocations, one for the `Substring` and the one for the final result. If your strings are small and this is not a hot path in your code, it'll be enough. If you care about maximising efficiency, use the new [`string.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netcore-3.1) overload from .NET Core 3.0:

```cs
var result = string.Create(alphabet.Length, alphabet, (span, source) => 
{
    for (var i = 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
    {
        span[i - 1] = source[i];
    }
    span[source.Length - 1] = source[0];
});
```

String.Create basically takes some state as its input and then a recipe on how to populate the `Span<char>` of the new string using that state. In this case, the state is your source `alphabet` string and the recipe is "iterate over the `source` skipping its first letter and copy it to the new string, then add the first letter of `source` at the end".

Note that the second solution is applicable only if you're creating a lot of such rotations. The one-liner is much simpler to understand.